# How can I select a TableViewCell that is inside a CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `CollectionView` that is scrolling horizontally. I have custom `CollectionViewCells` that have inside a `TableView` with three cells. It looks like this:
[![Here is a example of how it looks][1]][1]

[image]

This is the main `ViewController` where I have the `CollectionView`

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.viewModel.numberOfItems
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ItemCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ItemCell

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = self.viewModel.items[indexPath.item]
    }
}
```

And this is the *ItemCell* code that contains the tableview

```
class ItemCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DailySelectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: DailySelectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DailySelectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DailySelectionViewCell

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = "Item1"
        case 1:
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = "Item2"
        default:
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = "Item3"
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return view
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}
```

I want to click on the TableView cells that are inside the CollectionView cells. When I want to click on a `TableViewCell`, the touches are only registered on the `CollectionViewCell` and I can't click on any of the tableview cells inside the `CollectionViewCell`.

Comment: Create a delegate method in CollectionCell class and import its method in the Main class.

Answer (score 0):

By default `didSelectRowAt` must work.
As an assumption `DailySelectionViewCell` may contains some views with user interaction, namely subclassed from `UIControl`: `UIButton`, `UIDatePicker`, `UISegmentedControl` and so on. In this case `didSelectRowAt` not work and this is correct behavior.